# Key differences between C versions?

Tags: c

I agree that this could come off as a beginners question, but google returned absolutly 0 decent results when searching for this. I'm a C# programmer, never touched C or C++ in my life until now.

I just opened a C IDE and I've been asked what version of C to use, It defaultly selected 99, although C11 was the most recently version, so my heads saying select C11.

Can anyone explain the key differences, and which version I should be writing it, and how this will affect my application, does it even matter?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, the latest published standard obsoletes the previous ones, so you should be sticking to `C11`.

Comment: If you can use a C11 compiler then by all means use it. There is absolutely no benefit of sticking to an obsolete standard, lest you need to later adapt your program for prehistoric systems, or broken "C" compilers such as MSVC.

Comment: C11 has all the facilities that were in C99 except for one function, `gets()`, that you should never have used anyway.  Technically, some things that were mandatory in C99 are optional in C11, but for most purposes, C11 is a superset of C99. So, use C11 unless you’ve got a good reason not to do so.

Comment: And the C11 is superset of C99 *especially* in those compilers that could support them both.

Comment: If you are a beginner, just use the latest version and don't worry about all the detailed language features. It is good to be aware that there are older standards though, since some bad books and teachers are stuck in those.

Comment: Wikipedia has decent articles on C standards together with useful links. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)

Answer (score 4):

C11 has some optional features that aren’t fully supported by some compilers. Hence, C99 is often considered more portable.

However C11 adds some niceties such as anonymous unions within structs and other long awaited features including atomic variables, thread local storage, static assertions, etc’.

These things are often documented. For example, the added keywords are clearly marked in this [keyword documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword) (the [cppreference.com site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) has C documentation, despite it's name).

At the end of the day, being a beginner, you probably shouldn’t care too much just yet.

I code with C11, which means that my projects require newer compilers - but the differences are almost irrelevant except when I use inline functions or anonymous unions within structs - everything else can be implemented (albeit with more work) using libraries such as `pthread`, compiler extensions, inline asm or OS specific APIs.

Unlike some languages, the C standards go to great efforts to keep backwards compatibility - even though there are always exceptions that prove the rule, such as “clarifications” that preclude a previous interpretation of the language. A good example of such idiosyncrasies is the interpretation of the `inline` keyword between C versions (which you might or might not even notice).

For this reason it makes sense to default to C99 and only switch a project to C11 if that project requires C11 specific features.